# Why does SHFileOperationW create folder instead of move file?

Tags: c++, windows, shfileoperation

I have created own "Move" function based on `SHFileOperationW` like this:

```
int MoveItem(string strSourcePath, string strDestinationDirectory, string strNewName, bool bAllowOverwrite, bool bCreateDestinationDirectoryIfNotExist)
{
    int intPositionOfLastSlash;
    int intResult = 0;

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW sfosMove;

    string strNewPath;
    string strOldName;

    wchar_t a_wcNewPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    wchar_t a_wcSourcePath[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    wstring wsNewPath;
    wstring wsSourcePath;

    if((IsFileExist(strSourcePath) == false) && (IsFolderExist(strSourcePath) == false))
    {
        intResult = 0x7C;
    }

    else
    {
        if(IsFolderExist(strDestinationDirectory) == false)
        {
            if(bCreateDestinationDirectoryIfNotExist == false)
            {
                intResult = 0x7C;
            }
        }
    }

    if(intResult == 0)
    {
        intPositionOfLastSlash = strSourcePath.find_last_of("\\");
        strOldName = strSourcePath.substr(intPositionOfLastSlash + 1);

        if(strNewName == "")
        {
            strNewPath = strDestinationDirectory + "\\" + strOldName;
        }

        else
        {
            strNewPath = strDestinationDirectory + "\\" + strNewName;
        }

        if(bAllowOverwrite == false)
        {
            if(IsFileExist(strNewPath) == true)
            {
                intResult = 0x7E;
            }

            else if(IsFolderExist(strNewPath) == true)
            {
                intResult = 0x80;
            }
        }
    }

    if(intResult == 0)
    {
        /*- Source Path -*/
        wsSourcePath = Utf8StringToWstring(strSourcePath);

        StrCpyW(a_wcSourcePath, wsSourcePath.c_str());

        CopyMemory(a_wcSourcePath + lstrlenW(a_wcSourcePath), L"\0\0", 2);
        /*---------------*/

        /*- New Path -*/
        wsNewPath = Utf8StringToWstring(strNewPath);

        StrCpyW(a_wcNewPath, wsNewPath.c_str());

        CopyMemory(a_wcNewPath + lstrlenW(a_wcNewPath), L"\0\0", 2);
        /*-------------------------*/

        /*- Move Item -*/
        sfosMove.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_SILENT;
        sfosMove.pFrom = a_wcSourcePath;
        sfosMove.pTo = a_wcNewPath;
        sfosMove.wFunc = FO_MOVE;

        intResult = SHFileOperationW(&sfosMove);
        /*-------------*/
    }

    return intResult;
}
```

But The problem is when I use this function repeatedly, only first file is moved. The function creates folders with name of files.

For example:

> First file: abc.txt (This file is moved.) Second file: def.txt (This
> file is not moved. The function creates a folder named "def.txt")

Example usage creates the problem:

```
// "example_folder" is already present in "D:" drive.
int intResult;

intResult = MoveItem("C:\\ProgramData\\abc.txt", "D:\\example_folder", "", true, false);

if(intResult == 0)
{
     intResult = MoveItem("C:\\ProgramData\\def.txt", "D:\\example_folder", "", true, false);     
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], please? In any case, I would try to avoid use of 8-bit strings for paths on MS Windows, where the native FS path encoding is UTF-16. Wherever possible, use either a 16-bit string (wstring) or the C++ filesystem (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) library. If there some code you can't change (e.g. using UTF-8 in an 8-bit string), try to convert as early as possible.

Comment: Get in the habit of using `={}` when you declare a structure variable to make sure it's initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

☠️ Potential buffer overruns in several places here.

1. You should be allocating filename buffers with size `[MAX_PATH + 1]`, because they must have enough room to hold `MAX_PATH` characters *and* the terminating double-null.
2. You are only copying two bytes to the end of both your source and your destination paths, when your intent is to copy four. `L"\0\0"` is two wide characters, which is four bytes.

`CopyMemory(a_wcSourcePath + lstrlenW(a_wcSourcePath), L"\0\0", 2);`

Will this matter? Practically speaking, probably not, as you did initialize the buffer to all-zeroes. But it's a recipe for potential disaster.

3. You are copying to a buffer that may not have room for the characters you're copying. (It would *usually* work out, since presumably your source path is not longer than MAX_PATH, but you're dealing with conversions as well, from UTF-8 to UTF-16; for safety's sake, you should use StringCchCopy() or similar.)

```cpp
    wsSourcePath = Utf8StringToWstring(strSourcePath);

    StrCpyW(a_wcSourcePath, wsSourcePath.c_str());
```

4. You are not initializing the `SHFILEOPSTRUCTW` struct, so you have no way of knowing what sort of data is sitting in its various parts. Like this:

`SHFILEOPSTRUCTW sfosMove{};`

5. Will fixing all of those issues fix your problem? Maybe, but I don't know. (You have several functions in your pasted code that are not defined, for one thing.) When I run this code, more or less as you have it there, with the problems I've noted here fixed, it seems to work fine.

This whole answer might get downgraded because it's not definitively an "answer," but hopefully it saves you from some trouble down the line.

Comment: `MAX_PATH` [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry) of 260 includes the null, e.g., `"D:\some 256-character path string<NUL>"` is 260 characters.

Comment: @DaviGray Your answer has fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using the `std::filesystem` function to handle path manipulation and such.

I'd *probably* also use `std::filesystem::rename` to move the files, but there may be a case to make for using `MoveFileEx` instead. In particular, I haven't tried to check whether Microsoft's implementation of `rename` will actually move a file from one drive to another (but I'd guess it probably does).

So, a version using just `std::filesystem` stuff would be something like this:

```cpp
bool MoveItem(string sourcePath, string destDirectory, string destName, bool allowOverwrite, bool createDest) {

    namespace fs = std::filesystem;

    fs::path src{sourcePath};
    fs::path dest{destDirectory};

    if (!fs::exists(src))
        return false;

    if (createDest) {
        fs::create_directories(destDirectory); // does nothing if already exists
    } else if (!fs::is_directory(dest)) {
        return false;   // fail if it doesn't exist and we aren't allowed to create it.
    }

    dest = dest / (destName.empty() ? src.filename() : destName);

    if (!allowOverwrite && fs::exists(dest)) {
        return false;
    }

    std::error_code ec;
    fs::rename(src, dest, ec);
    return !ec;
}
```

If you wanted to use `MoveFileEx` instead, the last part of the code (after the `dest = dest / ...` line) would look something like this:

```cpp
DWORD flags{ MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED };

if (allowOverwrite)
    flags |= MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING;

return MoveFileEx(src.string().c_str(), dest.string().c_str(), flags) != 0;
```

I haven't tried to test every possible scenario (different combinations of flags, directory and/or files that already exist, moving between drives, over networks, etc.) but did a quick little test with code like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::vector<string> testNames { "a.test", "b.test", "c.test"};

    // Create a few files to test with:
    for (auto t : testNames) {
        std::ofstream o(t);
    }

    // move them to some innocuous destination:
    for (auto t : testNames) {
        MoveItem(t, "c:/junk", "", false, true);
    }
}
```